# How to develop Scoring Algorithms using functions

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create a word scoring algorithm that gives one point for every consonant and 3 point for every vowel. But every attempt I've tried for the past two weeks and I've failed which means something isn't clicking for me and I need help understanding what I'm doing wrong

I've searched all over the web and found numerous ways to check letters of a  I've tried customizing and using for my scoring algorithm and I still keep getting the wrong scoring output when testing each approach.

```
const oldScoreKey = {
  1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
  2: ['D', 'G'],
  3: ['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'],
  4: ['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'],
  5: ['K'],
  8: ['J', 'X'],
  10: ['Q', 'Z']
};


function transform(oldScoreKey) {
  const newScoreKey = {};
  for (const [letterValue, letterArr] of Object.entries(oldScoreKey)) {
    for (const letter of letterArr) {
      newScoreKey[letter.toLowerCase()] = letterValue;
    }
  }
  return newScoreKey;
}

console.log(transform(oldScoreKey));


//****************************************************
const input = require('readline-sync');

let word = (input.question("Enter a word please: "));
simpleScore = word.toLowerCase();



let score, i, sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  score = simpleScore[i];
  sum += transform(oldScoreKey)[score];

}
console.log(sum * 1);


vowelBonus = (word) => {
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  score = 0;
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  for (let letter in word) {}
  vowels.forEach((value) => {
    if (letter === value) {
      score += 3;
    } else if (letter !== value) {
      score += 1;
    }
  });
  return score;

};
```

I expect the output score to be (entering hello)41111 for the simple score and [function-vowelBonus], but the actual output should be

Simple Score:8
Bonus Vowels:9

Comment: Fix the indentation of the `vowelBonus` function and I think you'll see the problem.

Comment: You never call the vowelBonus function, either.

Comment: You don't need to loop over `vowels`. Just use `if(vowels.includes(letter))`

Comment: Correcting my previous comment (I'd mistakenly called it a "syntax error"), but you're closing your `for` loop before doing anything. I've formatted your code and it's now quite obvious as @Barmar notes: `for (let letter in word) {}`

Answer (score 3):

use a regexp and math to vastly simplify the operations:

```
const vowelBonus = word=>word.length + ((word.match(/[aeiou]/ig)||"").length * 2);
vowelBonus("Hello"); // == 9
```

you can repeat the last part of the function to assign different bonuses to different char ranges or lists of letters, multiplying them by the (bonus value -1):

`... + ((word.match(/[qz]/ig)||"").length * 9)`

Comment: @TylerRoper: you get one point for being anything, so vowels only get 2 bonus points.

Comment: @TylerRoper: I certainly agree it could use some additional clarity, i'm just posting the minimal example of a different approach. I might turn the bonus calculator into a callable function `bonus(str, rx)` if i were doing more groups than just vowels...

Answer (score 0):

I think above example with regex is better but since you wanted more verbose solution, here it is

```
    vowelBonus = (word) => {
      const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
      score = 0;
      word = word.toLowerCase();
      for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
         score += vowels.includes(word[i]) ? 3 : 1;
      }
      return score;    
    };
```